# What is the best way to access a database from a strictly HTML and javascript website?

Tags: html, database, web-services, postgresql

We are creating a website, and we are currently only using HTML5 and javascript. We need to be able to both read from and write to a database. We are using a postgressql database. What is your recommendation on how to go about querying the database? We are open to using other languages with our HTML and javascript to make this happen.

Comment: if you mean database querying from the client, idk but that would be completely unsecure. Anyone with programming knowledge could access the database, and delete/add/modify anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some server-side language. PHP, Ruby, Python would suffice.

Then it depends on how you want your UI to behave - you can either use POST/GET regular requests, or use ajax (asynchronous) requests.

HTML and Javascript are client-side technologies, and your sql server is on the server side. It is just not meant to work with a direct communication.

Even if there is some way to do this directly without any server-side language, (not that I'm aware of such), it would mean you'll have your database credentials on the client. And so anyone will be free to execute whatever queries he likes.

Comment: Why not do it? The scenario the OP is describing is perfectly valid. The OP is just asking about the missing piece in the puzzle (a backend that can serve data that can be consumed by JavaScript).

Comment: @Ates Goral - that's how my answer started. I'll clarify a bit.

Comment: That is what I'm asking. We just can't figure out how to tie up the backend.

Comment: @Newb - it will depend on the language you choose. I listed three. (there are more, of course). It is equally easy to do simple database operations with each.

Comment: We were wanting to use some kind of Java backend. Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Agreed. Making data available from a database using XML or JSON is quite a valid use case. The client-side javascript is only be used to format this data within the browser. Checkout Ajax handling using jQuery, very cool.

Comment: For java try DWR, see my answer below

Comment: @Mark O'Connor DWR is something I'd not recommend for beginners. @Newb well, I'd recommend Java immediately (having mostly Java background), but it is considered too heavyweight. You can use jQuery ajax capabilities with servlets on the backend, and JDBC. There are a lot of technologies, like Hibernate, spring, etc, but I can't just throw them in as suggestions, not knowing anything of your project.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use javascript, you can use AJAX... You can setup a server that processes all AJAX calls and connects to the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use a scripting language, like PHP, Ruby, Python, Perl, etc.

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons you will have to access the database on the server before moving the data to the client. This rules out any javascript, unless you have a readonly account for the database. For that reason I would advice you to go with a language like PHP, Java Tomcat or ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirements are indeed that "we can only use HTML/JavaScript" and "we need to access a database" then you have a couple of approaches, but they may not be the actual right approaches for you.

1. CouchDB (not PostgreSQL) is very JSON-friendly and is a database.  It can sit on the web server and be accessed directly from your JavaScript easily.  However, there is a *major* security risk here.  *Anyone* will have access to your database.  Depending on what the data is, it can be secured in various ways.  But it's still a huge risk.
2. Server-side JavaScript.  Look into node.js to run on the web server that's hosting the database.  Some pretty great projects have been based on that recently and "accessing a database" by itself should be pretty easy.

However, in normal day-to-day work, I'm going to have to agree with the other answers so far.  Use a server-side programming environment to handle the database stuff.  Unless your software actually fits into my suggestions above, in which case that's pretty awesome and go for it.

Comment: I'm don't understand why you consider couchdb a *major* security risk. Seems no better or worse than other available solutions.

Comment: @Mark O'Connor: It's not CouchDB that's the risk, it's accessing the database directly from the client-side code that's the risk.  Using a JSON-friendly DB doesn't address that.  It would require a lot of considerations about the data and the privacy of that data and the access to that data.  CouchDB would fit well with the JavaScript requirement, but the risk of client-driven data access remains.

Comment: Point taken, what you're talking about is limited and controlled access to the data via application APIs.... You can implement this with couchDB by enabling access to the view functions only (I would always recommend proxy'ing CouchDB behind a webserver like Apache for production systems).

Answer (score 0):

Lots of options, I'd suggest looking at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html). It enables server side java objects to be invoked from javascript clients.